# Dell Inspiron 15 3520 touchpad stop working after update

Tags: updates, dell, touchpad, inspiron

I bought the computer and install Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with a USB. Everything was working perfect, until I update and the touchpad start having problems. It works for a while, and then stop. I have an external mouse working fine.

Thanks for your help.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16
```